# UITableView with sectionIndexTitle bugs on rotation

Tags: iphone, uitableview, orientation

I have a UITableView with a sectionIndexTitles, and when I do a rotation, some cells are displayed like if I were on the previous orientation. When I don't have sectionIndexTitles, there is no problem. Is it just a bug in a library, or is there a secret tip I don't know to fix it ?

Tank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view controller's `-didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` try adding `[tableView reloadData]`.